# Visual Studio 2022 ServiceHub.IdentityHost.exe is perpetually maxed out on CPU

Tags: visual-studio

When running Visual Studio 2022, I find that ServiceHub.IdentityHost.exe (32 bit) is always pegged on CPU. If I log out of my account, CPU goes back to 0% on IdentityHost. And then when logging back in it kicks back up again. How can I figure out why this process is taking up so much CPU?

Edit: I'm running VS 17.5.5

[image: Task Manager]